# Embeding XLSX file into exe C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, embed, xlsx

I wrote code in VS17 and that code uses a database stored in `xlsx` file (so far it was used by reading the path of the file and reading it using OLE.DB):

```
string DataBase_File = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString(), String.Format("{0}", db_name));

string constr = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO""", DataBase_File);
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", SheetName), conn);
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

When I want to compile it into `.exe` file I added the file into the resources in the following way:

```
var fileString = namespace.Properties.Resources.DataBase;
```

However, the result I get is that fileString is `{bytes[28432]}`.

How can I make it a path or file that I can actually use the values in it cells as database?

Thank you

Comment: Save it out to a temp file?

Answer (score 0):

With line

```
var fileString = namespace.Properties.Resources.DataBase;
```

you're getting byte array (`byte[]`) and you're trying to use that byte array as path to your excel file.  Unfortunately, that cannot work. When specifying fileString as filename, you're getting `.ToString()` of that `byte[]`, hence `{bytes[28432]}`.

The only was to achieve your task is to write that bytes to (temporary) file, get data from it, and that delete temporary file. To achieve that, you can do following:

```
//temp file path
string tempDbPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
//temp db file name
string tempDbFile = "tempdb.xlsx";
//path + filename
string tempDBLocation = Path.Combine(tempDbPath, tempDbFile);
//get byte array from application's resources
byte[] resourceBytes = Properties.Resources.DataBase;

//write all bytes to specified location
File.WriteAllBytes(tempDBLocation, resourceBytes);

//connect and select data as usual
string constr = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO""", tempDBLocation);
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", "Sheet1$"), conn);
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}

//delete temp file
File.Delete(tempDBLocation);
```